# npm --save-dev install react-cron: success. module not found. Also fails on Run-Kit

Tags: reactjs, cron, npm-install, runkit

import 'react-cron'
... cannot find module react-cron.

npm install successful; node_modules contains react-cron dir.

Anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Are you doing `import reactCron from 'react-cron'` ?

Comment: yes.  same error.  also have import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip' for instance.  npm install of react-cron shows it has installed ui-workbench@1.0.0 /Users/akpeter/ui-workbench
└── react-cron@0.0.1    but then fails on npm start with error 'Error: Cannot find module 'react-cron' from '/Users/....'

Comment: tried running it in run-kit (the nodejs environ).  the require('react-cron'); there failed to find the package as well.

Comment: https://runkit.com/npm/react-cron